# NoMethodError on 'release_path' during chef deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I'm pretty new to Chef deployments, and I'm trying to deploy a rails app with OpsWorks. The trouble is with asset precompilation.

I have this recipe to perform precompilations:

```
execute "rake assets:precompile" do   
  cwd release_path
  command "bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace"    
  environment "RAILS_ENV" => "production"
end
```

When I deploy with Chef, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: undefined method `release_path' for Chef::Resource::Execute
```

What's weird is that every example recipe I can find makes use of the `release_path` helper. How could it not be defined here?

Comment: Are you using the `deploy` resource outside of the `execute`? There, the `release_path` method exists, but when this is on top level of your recipe, `release_path` is not defined. Please show your complete code.

Comment: That is the complete content of `precompile.rb`, which is my recipe. Should I wrap this code in a `deploy` resource?

Comment: It depends, if you want to use the `deploy` resource - you don't have to. Just replace `release_path` with e.g. `"/usr/local/myapp"`

Comment: Actually you should, of course, replace it with the path to your rails app ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using `node[:deploy]['appshortname'][:deploy_to]`. My full recipe is below:

```
node[:deploy].each do |application, deploy|
  execute "rake assets:precompile" do   
    cwd "#{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current"
    command "bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace"

    environment deploy[:environment_variables].merge(
      "RAILS_ENV" => deploy[:rails_env]
    )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do precompile on a rails application on opsworks:

This code is placed in your applications deploy folder, in a file called "before_migrate.rb" in /approot/deploy/before_migrate.rb.

The environment variables are created in the application defined in opsworks.

```
rails_env = new_resource.environment["RAILS_ENV"]
secret_key_base = new_resource.environment["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]
devise_secret_key = new_resource.environment["DEVISE_SECRET_KEY"]

Chef::Log.info("Precompiling assets for RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}...")
Chef::Log.info("SECRET_KEY_BASE=#{secret_key_base}, DEVISE_SECRET_KEY=#{devise_secret_key}")

execute "rake assets:precompile" do
  cwd release_path
  command "RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake assets:precompile"

  environment "RAILS_ENV" => rails_env
  environment "SECRET_KEY_BASE" => secret_key_base
  environment "DEVISE_SECRET_KEY" => devise_secret_key
end
```